# How to manage AWS cloud search version ID?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud

I'm writing a library in order to help everyone using Amazon cloud search.

With cloud search when you update a document you need to specify the id of the document (of course) and the version of the document you want to upgrade to.

**If the specify version number is smaller than the current version the update don't append.**

So how to make sure I update my record every time I do an update?

The Ruby project [aws_cloud_search](https://github.com/aaronbrethorst/aws_cloud_search/blob/master/lib/aws_cloud_search/document.rb) is using a timestamp in order to keep the version number always higher but:

- As the maximum version number is 4294967295 for AWS cloud search. So
  it will not work any more after the 07 Feb 2106
- If you run two updates within the same second then the last update
  (the more important one) will be ignore

Comment: Are you projecting the software will still be in use on 08 Feb 2106?

Comment: @Christopher Maybe not (some might) but still I have the 2nd problem. "running two updates within the same second"

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this that you liked?

Comment: @biggusjimmus not really :-)

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the timestamp approach, which appears to be the standard answer from everybody, including the docs, the only approach that I've found that works is to keep track of the version number elsewhere, and increment it as changes happen.

Of course, this approach only works if the object that you're trying to represent in the cloud search document can be accessed from somewhere else where presumably you have some sort of atomicity.